# How do I paste into Mathematica from Word and maintain carriage returns?

Tags: format, wolfram-mathematica, copy-paste, carriage-return

Carriage returns and certain spaces seem to disappear when pasting in Mma (v. 11).  For example, when I cut the following text in word (formatted as such):

```
xmin = 0; xmax = 1;(*x-axis domain*)
ymin = 0; ymax = 1;(*y-axis domain*)
zmin = 0; zmax = 1;(*z-axis domain*)
E1 = x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0 && x + y + z < 1;(*domain of solid region E1*)
RegionPlot3D[E1, {x,xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, {z, zmin, zmax},
  PlotPoints -> 50, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Solid Region E", 
  ImageSize -> Small]
```

It comes out like this which is not ideal:

```
xmin = 0; 
xmax = 1;
(*x-axis domain*)ymin = 0; 
ymax = 1;
(*y-axis domain*)zmin = 0; 
zmax = 1;
(*z-axis domain*)E1 = x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0 && x + y + z < 1;
(*domain of solid region E1*)
RegionPlot3D[E1, {x,xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, {z, zmin, zmax},PlotPoints -> 50,
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},PlotLabel -> "Solid Region E",ImageSize -> Small]
```

Is there a way to maintain returns and spaces when copying and pasting across programs.  Please advise.

Thanks, K

Comment: I'd suggest not using word in the first place. Plenty of good free text editors available.

Answer (score 1):

Not particularly straightforward:

Make an empty cell, select it. Go to menu: Format > Style > Program.  Paste your code into the cell, select the cell and convert the style back: Format > Style > Input.

Better just to format your how-to document in such a way that it pastes into Mathematica without changing.

Answer (score 0):

Scrape your text in Word and put it in your clipboard

Start Mathematica

Left click inside the notebook

Type an x (or any other character)

Right click the cell bracket on the right side of the notebook enclosing the x

Gently slide the mouse down to Style and then over to left click Text

Scrape over the x to highlight it

Paste your clipboard into Mathematica replacing the x

Right click the cell bracket on the right side of the notebook enclosing the expression

Gently slide the mouse down to Style and then over to left click Input

and your expression will be in Mathematica while preserving your returns and spaces.

Comment: Thank you for quick response.  While this does indeed address my question it introduces another issue:  the quotes comeup rounded which appears to break code.  I specifically went to the effort in Word of undoing auto correct for rounded quotes such that my straight quotes remain when I directly cut and paste into Input cell.  

My intent is to create a how-to-document in word such that a user can cut and paste into mathematica intuitively without having to worry about things getting messed up and not working.  Other ideas are welcome.